# Generating and Summing Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm relatively new to R, so forgive me for what I believe to be a relatively simple question.

I have data in the form

```
    1   2   3   4   5
A   0   1   1   0   0
B   1   0   1   0   1
C   0   1   0   1   0
D   1   0   0   0   0
E   0   0   0   0   1
```

where A-E are people and 1-5 are binaries of whether or not they have that quality. I need to make a matrix of A-E where cell A,B = 1 if the sum of any quality 1-5 for A & B sums to 2. (If they share at least one quality). The simple 5x5 would be:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
A   1               
B   1   1           
C   1   0   1       
D   0   1   0   1   
E   0   1   0   0   1
```

I then need to sum the entire matrix. (Above would be 9). I have thousands of observations, so I can't do this by hand. I'm sure there is an easy few lines of code, I'm just not experienced enough.

Thanks!

EDIT: I've imported the data from a .csv file with the columns (1-5 above) as variables, in the real data I have 40 variables. A-E are unique ID observations of people, approximately 2000. I would also like to know how to first convert this into a matrix, in order to execute the great answers you have already provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use matrix multiplication here

```
out <- tcrossprod(m)
#   A B C D E
# A 2 1 1 0 0
# B 1 3 0 1 1
# C 1 0 2 0 0
# D 0 1 0 1 0
# E 0 1 0 0 1
```

Then set the diagonal to one, if required

```
diag(out) <- 1
```

As DavidA points out in comments `tcrossprod` is a basically doing `m %*% t(m)`

Several ways to them calculate the `sum`l here is one

```
sum(out[upper.tri(out, diag=TRUE)] , na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I do understand this, and it should work, but I have to ask a an easier question, I have the data now as variables. How can I change this into a matrix without having to type in all the numbers?

Comment: You're welcome. If you have each row you can use `rbind` to bind all them together ans it will form a `matrix`. Otherwise, if your data is a `data.frame` you can use `as.matrix`. If either f these dont work, can you add a small edit to your question showing how the data is stored, thanks

Comment: Thanks, I added the edit above. I've imported the data from a .csv file with the columns (1-5 above) as variables, in the real data I have 40 variables. A-E are unique ID observations of people, approximately 2000. I would also like to know how to first convert this into a matrix, in order to execute the great answers you have already provided.

Comment: So you have just one dataset read in with `read.csv` that has all the data?

Comment: Yes with the column heads, which are the variables, and the binaries the output, one file .csv

Comment: hmm... so does `m <- as.matrix(yourdata)` work in converting it to a matrix. If not, can you post  a small bit of your data using `dput(yourdata[1:5, 1:5])`. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75235/discussion-between-chrisdh-and-user20650).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer`, if `m` is your square matrix:

```
f = Vectorize(function(u,v) any(colSums(m[c(u,v),])>1)+0L)

res = outer(1:ncol(m), 1:ncol(m), FUN=f)
colnames(res) = row.names(res) = rownames(m)

#  A B C D E
#A 1 1 1 0 0
#B 1 1 0 1 1
#C 1 0 1 0 0
#D 0 1 0 1 0
#E 0 1 0 0 1
```

**Data:**

```
m = structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"), NULL))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this? (of cource not as elegant as the `tcrossprod` solution):

```
d <- dim(m)
ind <- expand.grid(1:d[1],1:d[1])
M <- matrix(as.numeric(apply(cbind(m[ind[,2],],m[ind[,1]]), 1, 
+   function(x) sum(x[1:d[1]] == 1 & x[(d[1]+1):(d[1]*2)] == 1) >=1)), ncol = d[1])

rownames(M) = colnames(M) = rownames(m)
M
  A B C D E
A 1 1 1 0 0
B 1 1 0 1 1
C 1 0 1 0 0
D 0 1 0 1 0
E 0 1 0 0 1
```